# MySQL Table Import Wizard does not detect xlsx files on my pc (mac)?

Tags: mysql, import

I am trying to import a xlxs files to an empty database in MySQL Workbench. However, the Table Import Wizard does not detect/recognize two xlxs files that is saved on my computer (Mac). How can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

I tried but it cannot detect/select the files.

Comment: you need csv files for that, so export it from excel#

Comment: And never use the MySQL Workbench export wizard. It is super slow, and buggy. It has even been reported to lose data during the import. I recommend using command-line tools like [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html).